# SSRS AVG IIF is displaying a different value from my SUM IIF divided by a number (with date range)

Tags: reporting-services

I want to take the average cases given 3 months.

Suppose I have a data like this

```
**Month**      | **Cases**
January 2017   |   3981
February 2017  |   3402
March 2017     |   3683
April 2017     |   2920
```

Here is a sample code:

```
=Sum(IIF(CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) >=  
     DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -3, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) 
     And CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) <= 
     DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)), 
     Fields!Total_Cases.Value, 0))/3
```

which is working and giving the correct values in SSRS.

So by using this code, with a parameter period equal to April 2017, the average will be computed like

```
DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -3, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) = Jan2017
DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -2, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) = Feb2017
DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) = Mar2017
Total Cases = (3981 + 3402 + 3683)/3 = 3689
```

My problem is that this doesn't take into consideration the null values. So like when there are only 2 available values, the sum will still be divided by 3 instead of 2.

So I decided to try this code:

```
=Avg(IIF(CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) >= 
     DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -3, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) 
     And CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) <= 
     DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)), 
     Fields!Total_Cases.Value, Nothing))
```

My problem now is that it doesn't display the same value as the code I did for the sum divided by 3. By running this code, it will display an average equal to **527** and I don't know where it came from.

Please help me. I'm stuck on this problem for a week now.

Comment: The SSRS Function `AVG` will ignore any NULL/Nothing values when calculating so this should give you what you want. Can you edit your question and post a sample of data from your dataset that illustrates the problem along with the result you are currently getting and what you expect.

Comment: Please check the latest post.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it works perfectly for me. I'll add an answer shortly just so you can see what I did and the results.

Comment: It has been resolved now. Apparently, the problem is not on the code but on how my dataset was being interpreted in terms of its granularity in report builder. Thanks for your input anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't constitute an answer as I can't reproduce the problem but this is step-by-step what I did to achieve the desired results.

Created New Report

Added a dataset with the following query to replicate your test data

```
CREATE TABLE #t(ServiceYrMnth varchar(20), Total_Cases float)

INSERT INTO #t VALUES
('January 2017', 3981),
('February 2017', 3402),
('March 2017', 3683),
('April 2017', 2920)

SELECT * FROM #t
```

Added a simple table showing both columns

Added 4 Total rows as follows (some are not required but helped with testing)

Simple Sum of All Rows [Sum(Total_Cases)]

Simple Avg of All Rows [Avg(Total_Cases)]

Calculated Sum 1st 3 Months. This uses your first expression

```
=Sum(IIF(CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) >=  
     DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -3, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) 
     And CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) <= 
     DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)), 
     Fields!Total_Cases.Value, 0))
```

Calculated Avg 1st 3 Months. This uses the same expression but changing `Sum` to `Avg` and changing the final `0` to `Nothing` which appears to be what you have already. The final expression was this.

```
=Avg(
    IIF(
        CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) >= DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -3, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value)) 
         And CDate(Fields!ServiceYrMnth.Value) <= DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, CDate(Parameters!Period.Value))
         , Fields!Total_Cases.Value
         , Nothing
         )
     )
```

Finally I added a Text parameter called Period and set the default to 'April 2017'

Here's the report design.

[image]

Running the report with all 4 periods populated gives this.

[image]

Everything looks as expected.

Next I replaced `3683` with `NULL` in the dataset query and ran the report again. This time we get the following.

[image]

Again, the results are exactly what I would expect.